# Unable to start debug IPA on iOS 6, it runs perfectly on iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, crash, ipa

On console, I have this message:

> backboardd[51] : BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 23:
>   (ipc/send) timed out (0x10000004)

Then it crashes. The crash report is:

```
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:         abc [3243]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/...
Identifier:      abc
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-10-...
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.abc failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 20.910 (user 20.910, system 0.000), 52% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 19.898, 50% CPU
```

The release version works fine on both iOS 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that your application initial setup takes too long to complete. Try to modify your **application:didFinishLaunching** method to do less tasks.

The new iOS6 has a built-in timer that closes the application if it takes too long to start.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to divide your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method code to different function calls and make those calls in background using the threads other then main and make sure that `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method returns as soon as possible

you can use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//put your code
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, putting this into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and applicationDidFinishLaunching resolved the crash issue. However, it still doesn't start and I receive timeout errors. (CoreAnimation and BKSendGSEvent.)

Comment: When I run it from XCode, it goes fine. But when I make an IPA with the archiving tool, or I simply drag the .app file to Itunes, it freezes. (At least doesn't crash anymore.)

Comment: then you can try to make new thread ivar and use that thread instead of the dispatch_get_main_queue()

Comment: Thanks! Let's continue the discussion in [12972983](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972983/program-runs-from-xcode-but-causes-time-out-as-ad-hoc-deployment-ipa)

Answer (score 1):

Your app is taking to long to start and is then killed by iOS.

Check that `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` returns as soon as posible.

There might be something in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` which work differntly on iOS 6 and there for taken more time. A good idea is the dispatch that task.